# Lag a variable n times

Tags: r

I am trying to lead a variable in a regression by more than one space

i.e if i have:

```
       x                            Y
   0000023                  -0.1290163
   0000045                  -0.2226193
   12000000                  -0.2464814
   2468476                  -0.1652926
   0400                  -0.3799570
   00020                  -0.3929633
```

I would like to perform the regression of x on Y using data by leading X twice

```
       x  
        0
        0                         Y
   0000023                  -0.1290163
   0000045                  -0.2226193
   12000023                  -0.2464814
   2468476                  -0.1652926
                           -0.3799570
                           -0.3929633
```

I tried creating a new variable using :

```
lead<-c(x[-N],0)
```

But changing N has no effect, it only leads  once

Answer (score 1):

You can use `head` and `tail`:

```
DF <- read.table(text="x                            Y
0000023                  -0.1290163
0000045                  -0.2226193
12000000                  -0.2464814
2468476                  -0.1652926
0400                  -0.3799570
00020                  -0.3929633", header=TRUE)


lm(head(Y, -2) ~ tail(x, -2), data=DF)
```